# Does HP aCC compiler support template as template parameter?

Tags: c++, gcc, acc

I have following code

```
template <int b> class a {
};

template < int b, template<int> class c > class d {
public:
  d(){
    new c<b>();
  }
};

int main(){
  return 0;
}
```

Compiled with `GCC`, no error.

However in HP `aCC`, the following error occurred:

```
Error 419: "a.cpp", line 7 # 'c' is used as a type, but has not been defined as a type.
     new c();
         ^

Error 318: "a.cpp", line 7 # A template name was expected instead of ''. Did you forget to define the template?
     new c();
         ^^^^
```

Now I'm wondering if the HP `aCC` compiler supports template as template parameter.

Did I make any mistake in above code?

Comment: A quick check with GCC 4.7.1 tells me that no, it seems that your compiler does not support that.

Comment: Also, Clang 3.3 and Intel 13.0.0 accept this code.

Comment: The code looks fine. I hear aCC needs a command-line option `+hpxstd98` to enable better conformance, can you try it?

Comment: I tried +hpxstd98, but my compiler doesn't support this option.

Comment: My compiler version:        $Revision: 92453-07 linker linker crt0.o B.11.47 051104 $
        HP aC++ B3910B A.03.73
        HP aC++ B3910B A.03.66 Classic Iostream Library
        HP aC++ B3910B A.03.66 Language Support Library

Comment: Well, yes. Your compiler is something around ten years old. Get a newer one?